# How to make emacs to launch sql modes runtime window always at the bottom?

Tags: config, sql-mode

When using `M x sql-postgres` to launch the SQL mode window, emacs (as of 25.x) seems to be making smart choices about where the SQL run-time window will show. That is, it splits the viewport and shows the runtime at the bottom by default. But when I resize emacs to full screen (or enough width), SQL runtime shows on the right hand side. My question is:

*Can one make the new SQL run time window to always appear at the bottom?*

(I observed similar behavior for python and other programming modes when launching the runtime window. Sometimes, I just felt it easier that the runtime always pop up at the same location.)

Comment: Check the value of `split-width-threshold`. It sounds like you might want to set it higher than the width of a full screen Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display-buffer-alist`:

```
(add-to-list
 'display-buffer-alist
 '((lambda (buffer action)
     (with-current-buffer buffer
       (derived-mode-p 'sql-interactive-mode)))
   display-buffer-at-bottom))
```

Or use [shackle](https://depp.brause.cc/shackle/) with a rule like this

```
(setq shackle-rules '((sql-interactive-mode :select t :align 'below :size 0.25)))
```